# bootstrap tag with ajax support, need javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, callback, tags

I am using bootstrap tag with ajax for autocomplete feature..
what I try to do is input a in textfield 
it will show something from my list and a selection box show below..
like when I keyin A, the selection box below will shows Ada, Amy, from my db starts with a. when I select one, it will add as a tag in textbox. user can input multiple tags. or if there's no one match, the tag can be created by free text input.

i use this bootstrap tag 
http://fdeschenes.github.io/bootstrap-tag/

from his document: 
The data source to query against. May be an array of strings or a function. The function is passed two arguments, the query value in the input field and the process callback. The function may be used synchronously by returning the data source directly or asynchronously via the process callback's single argument.

I've create a javascript function for getting my source...
I try and success get my result in json, but it cannot show the autocomplete tag

i created a ajax fucntion to get the suggestion list.
the console.log ('return data' ) can show what I want. but  the result cannot show in the suggestion selection box.

the html form..

```
                    <div class="label_wrap label_more">
                        <label for="form-field-2">
                            Taggings
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group input_newadd">
                            <div class="inline tag_div_in tags_verttag">
                                <input type="text" class="tags_in" name="tags_verttag"
                                       id="form-field-tags_verttag"
                                       data-provide="taggings"
                                       value="" placeholder="Enter tags ..."/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

the js

```
    $('#form-field-tags_verttag').tag({
        placeholder: $('#form-field-tags_verttag').attr('placeholder'),
        source: function (query, process) {
            jQuery.get("/search/searchallex", {
                keyword: query
            }, function (data) {
                console.log('return data:'+data['data']);
                process (data['data']);
            });
        }
    });
```

It's expected that the data will list out in the selection box below the textfield. but when I keyin a, it just show several "A" in selection box.
doesn't show ["ada","april","amy"]

i am not good at javascript callback function, is it the reason I get the wrong data?

Pls help and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the php return a string,,, (stupid..)
voncert to array then all problem solved.

```
$('#form-field-tags_verttag').tag({
    placeholder: $('#form-field-tags_verttag').attr('placeholder'),
    source: function (query, process) {
        jQuery.get("/search/searchallex", {
            keyword: query
        }, function (data) {
```

//                console.log('return data:'+data['data']);
//                process (data['data']);

```
                var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data['data']);
                console.log(JSONObject);      
                process (JSONObject);
        });
    }
});
```